# Initialization list: cannot convert ‘Participant’ to ‘unsigned int’ in initialization

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, linked-list, initializer-list

I am getting a very weird error when trying to compile a simple linked list that stores "Participants". However I am clearly giving it the correct data, that can be confirmed because it works when not using initialization lists (doing a assign operator "=").

Bellow are the relevant code blocks:

```
struct Participant
{
    unsigned startNumber;
    std::string forename;
    std::string surname;
    std::string club;
    float finishTime;
};

struct ListNode
{
    ListNode* next;
    Participant data;
};

Participant tempData {list->data}; //error occurs here.
```

Below is the error i get:

```
List.cpp:15:36: error: cannot convert ‘Participant’ to ‘unsigned int’ in initialization
```

Replacing:

```
Participant tempData {list->data};
```

With:

```
Participant tempData = list->data;
```

Compiles and runs smoothly.

```
g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
CrunchBang (Debian 7 'Wheezy')
```

Any ideas on what the problem is?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Best Regards, Erik Jansson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to perform aggregate initialisation of a `Participant`, where the first element is an `unsigned int`. Naturally the one argument you give in that initialisation list is not a match for that initialisation.

I'd say this is a good example of why switching to C++11-style `{}` initialisation absolutely everywhere for no reason whatsoever is error-prone.

What is wrong with:

```
Participant tempData = list->data;
```

or:

```
Participant tempData(list->data);
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with them :D I am currently learning c++ (university) and we have been taught to always use them. Guess they were wrong! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Nice to hear of a Uni being cutting-edge but, yes, they are. :)